# Scraping a reactjs website using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, screen-scraping, headless-browser

I have everything set up to run a headless browser using Selenium in Java. I cant figure out now what I need to do to extract elements from this ReactJS website (the site contains either ReactJS or Javascript I'm not sure).

I feel like I may be approaching this wrong and/or missing some libraries that would help me along the way.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really going to be relevant what framework is used client side to do the rendering. You are only interested in scraping the final html it produces

Comment: I cant seem to scrape the final html. There are multiple words inside each "class" separated by spaces (none of which work when i try findByElementClass). Is there a way to download the html and then scrape the data from that?

Comment: Are you setting delay to let asynchronous javascript render?

Comment: @charlietfl I am not sure. How would I do this in Java?

Comment: through selenium api

Comment: Ok will do. I should also mention that the class names are often 4 or 5 different names together with spaces in between. Is this unusual?

Comment: not really. An element can have numerous classes. Typically repeating elements will have common class though even if it has others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179338/discussion-between-daveyman123-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do Web Interface tests or scraping with Java + Selenium, I advise you to use the [NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io/) Open Source Framework.

Comment: Could you please provide some advice on references/guides to setting up NoraUi with java. seems im a bit in over my head.

Comment: https://noraui.github.io/#installationInstructions https://noraui.github.io/#quickStartGuide and demo on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0fSEfmApGE